# Generalized Lotka–Volterra equations to explore filling of energy levels in mixtures of interacting diatomic molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, spectroscopy, gas, molecules

Did anyone saw any application of Generalized Lotka–Volterra equations to explore filling of energy levels in mixture of interacting diatomic molecules. The idea is to consider molecular interaction and energy levels fillings as competition and rewrite GLV parameters as probabilities to fill the certain energy level.

Comment: This is not a good question as the answer depends on the individuals and just of the form yes/no.  Perhaps you can transform this into a question that can be answered using physics?